# How to create a vertical linear gradient for a GTK separator

Tags: python, css, gtk3

I'm using Gtk 3.10 and I am experimenting for the first time some of the CSS theming aspects of Gtk programming.

Taking from the gtk3-demo I noted this excellent example

[image]

From the associated CSS file I can see that this "handle bar" is actually a gradient fill centered:

```
.pane-separator {
  background-color: alpha(white, 0.80);
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, transparent 1px, #999 1px, #999 4px, transparent 4px);
  background-size: 40px auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.pane-separator:prelight {
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, transparent 1px, #555 1px, #555 4px, transparent 4px);
}
```

So in my naivety I thought I would apply this to my Gtk application -  I wanted the vertical pane-separators to have this centered "handle" as well as the horizontal pane-separators

[image]

Well as you can see, the horizontal pane-separators worked (1) but the vertical pane-separators (2) & (3) placed the "handle" at the top.

I thought I would use the `transform: rotate(90deg);` from this [CSS example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20649215/1626229) but this didnt work in Gtk

```
gi._glib.GError: gtkthemeoverride.css:18:11'transform' is not a valid property name
```

I'm using this as my reference answer to use Python & the Gtk.CssProvider() to load my equivalent of "style.css"

How do I centre the vertical handle in Gtk - what changes to the CSS file do I need?

---

I tried to use "90deg" in the CSS element - `background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, transparent 1px, #999 1px, #999 4px, transparent 4px);`

This was the result - no handle in the vertical pane - but a 90deg rotation in the horizontal (just testing - I'll be using separate CSS elements later to differentiate between vertical and horizontal)

[image]

Comment: The first (optional) value of the linear-gradient is an angle value. Have you tried this for the vertical bars? Such as `linear-gradient(0deg, ...);`

Comment: thanks for the hint - I've updated the Q with the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
.pane-separator#vertical_paned {

  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, transparent, transparent 1px, #999 1px, #999 4px, transparent 4px);
  background-size: 100% 15%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.pane-separator:prelight#vertical_paned {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, transparent, transparent 1px, #555 1px, #555 4px, transparent 4px);
}
```

In the end the key parts I found was to use the [direction element](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp) of a gradient *to left* or *to right*, together with the [background-size](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_backgrounds.asp) expressed in terms of percentage width vs height - in this case, 100% width, 15% height.

In addition I added the named CSS element *#vertical_paned*.  Every python widget can be defined with a name using the method *widget.set_name(name)*, thus I defined both vertical panes as shown in the picture with the same name *vertical_paned* and the CSS element specific to these panes was applied.

Answer (score 0):

The `background-position` property takes two values, one for horizontal and one for vertical. They both default to 0%, which is why your original attempt appeared at the top: it was centered horizontally but not vertically.

Try this:

```
background-position: center center;
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for the feedback - i tried `background-position: center center;`with and without 90deg for the first parameter for linear-gradient but no joy.  The position remained at the top of the vertical pane.